# In Oracle SQL, does null = null?

Tags: mysql, oracle, null

I can't test if `null = null`, since I don't have the permissions to create data on the database i'm using.

My question is:

If I have a table with two rows:

```
Row 1: ItemID = 1, CollectionID = 1, Price = null
Row 2: ItemID = 2, CollectionID = 1, Price = null
```

And my query is as follows:

```
SELECT CollectionID
  FROM my_table TB
 WHERE Price >= (SELECT avg(Price)
                   FROM my_table 
                  WHERE TB.CollectionID = CollectionID);
```

Will `collectionID 1` be displayed in the results? 
In other words, we have *null* values for `TB.CollectionID` and for `CollectionID`.

Does `TB.CollectionID = CollectionID` ?

Answer (score 9):

No, `NULL` is equal to no other value, including another instance of `NULL` (this is true for SQL in general, not just Oracle <sup>(a)</sup>).

That's because `NULL` is *not* a value, rather it's an entity meaning "unknown", "not available" or "not applicable".

That's why, if you want to check if something is NULL, you use:

```
where something is null
```

rather than:

```
where something = null
```

If you *do* want to treat `NULL` values as equal, you can do something like:

```
where TB.CollectionID = CollectionID
   or (TB.CollectionID is null and CollectionID is null)
```

but that sort of goes against the whole *concept* of SQL tri-value logic.

> And, as an aside, don't let your lack of power on your *own* systems limit what you can do. See [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), for example, which can let you create and manipulate databases at will.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Though, of course, some DBMS don't always *follow* the standard in ways that make sense, such as a certain large vendor (no names, but it starts with `o` and ends with `racle` <sup>(b)</sup>) not being able to store an zero-length string into a varchar-type field, instead coercing it to be `NULL` :-)

<sup>(b)</sup> Or perhaps in this case, it makes much more sense to say it starts with `NULL` and ends with `oracle` :-)

Comment: @Louis-Philippe Baillargeon Note that this is a rule of SQL. It isn't specific to Oracle.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the `DECODE` function is an exception to this rule and it _does_ treat two `NULL`s as equal.